# Multi-tenant Single DB plugin and tenant_id column

Tags: grails, plugins, multi-tenant

I am using multi-tenant single db plugin in grails and it requires all the table to have "tenant_id" column. Is there any way to make the plugin lookup different column like "idclient" instead of "tenant_id"? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the column mapping in your domain classes.

```
static mapping = {
    tenantId column: 'idclient' 
}
```